# How to fill up Choice Field (Drop down) using SharePoint List data?

Tags: cognito-forms, sharepoint

Is it possible to pull out data from SharePoint list and filled up Choice Field (With Type = Drop down)?
I am able to send data to SharePoint list. I want to pull data for once specific drop down from SharePoint list. 
For example: 
I have one list named "Products" with values "Product1", "Product2", "Product3" (Title column in SharePoint list). I want to pull out these values in Choice Field (Drop down) into my Form.
Please let me know if this is possible?

Comment: I had thought this was about Microsoft SharePoint.  Please be as specific as possible the next time.

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

This is a great idea and is a feature we are going to look into in the future. You can follow our progress for this feature over on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/pxdTryVV).

Comment: Thank you. Can you please suggest me the timeline how long will it take to make available this functionality? I am also planning for other alternate solutions/tools.